# How to configure UV4L?

Tags: raspicam, uv4l

I have been trying to edit the .conf file for raspicam to change the default resolution; however, I can seem to figure out the right command for enabling configuration permissions.

When I access the .conf file:

```
    $ nano /etc/uv4l/uv4l-raspicam.conf
```

I am alerted that I do not have write permission.
How do I cure this?
I've tried to use:

```
    $ uv4l --server-option = --config-password=myp4ssw0rd
```

But I get "'<'alert'>' [core] No device detected.

Really confused and I'm worried that the answer is a simple one that I am not experienced enough to see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't use a conf file; I just start it from a shell script. Although according to `man u4vl` they use the same options, in my experience it seems hard to get it them to work from the file (e.g., `vflip` alone causes an error at start; `vflip=true` does not, but is ignored) -- so I worry the ones that are harder to check, such as `mem-lock`, aren't necessarily being applied either.

The script approach is a file that looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

exec uv4l --sched-rr --mem-lock --driver raspicam \
--width 960 --height 540 --framerate 30 \
--encoding mjpeg --vflip --hflip
```

(My camera is mounted upside down).  The web server is started by default and eats about 8 MB/s this way *per connection* (meaning you can only really do one); at full resolution it is closer to 12 MB/s, and I have not found a way to maintain a stable connection to a pi that way (it dies after a few seconds, although the server is obviously still running because you can reconnect right away).  See the last paragraph below about checking how the camera ends up *actually* set.

WRT to your specific problem, if you can issue the command this way, then according to the man page "options specified via command line have higher priority" vs. a configuration file, so you won't have to worry about one.  **Note you will either have to `su root` or add `sudo` between `exec` and `uv4l` for the above to work.**  Using `su root` is also one way to solve your config file access problem, a couple more are suggested below.

I don't seem to have a system wide config file (this is not on Raspbian) and since it seems more and not less awkward to use I haven't bothered trying to create one.

However:

> I am alerted that I do not have write permission. How do I cure this?

Presumably it has superuser permissions.  You could try:

```
sudo chmod 775 /etc/uv4l
sudo chgrp pi /etc/uv4l/uv4l-raspicam.conf
sudo chmod 664 /etc/uv4l/uv4l-raspicam.conf
```

And that should make the file permanently editable by user `pi`. It could be that `uv4l` won't start using a conf file editable by anyone other that root,<sup>1</sup> so you may end up having to reverse that (755 instead of 775, then `root` instead of `pi`, the 644 instead of 664) and instead use:

```
sudoedit /etc/uv4l/uv4l-raspicam.conf
```

I believe by default this uses `nano` so you should be okay with that.

You can stop the current instance with

```
sudo kill uv4l $(pidof uv4l)
```

So you can restart it again with different options, but you can also affect (at least) the http server output from `http://whatever.pi:8080/panel` -- this will also show how the camera is really set, e.g. I notice I don't actually get 960x540, I get 960x544.  If you are aware of this control interface it works well to play with settings dynamically.

---

<sup>1. An easy way to check that would be to write your own as `pi` then try `sudo uv4l --config-file mytest.conf`.</sup>

Comment: use vflip=1 or vflip=yes in the conf. file